# Local access only to router when encryption enabled

Tags: laptop, wireless-networking, router, wpa, wpa2-psk

I have a Wireless Huawei HG520b Router and a Toshiba Satellite laptop. They can connect fine via ethernet, and the router has a connection to the internet no problem.

But if I try to connect the laptop to the router wirelessly it can only get a connection to the router, not though to the internet. "Local access only"

What's more, if I ping the router when connected it fails with "Request timed out" or "no path to host", nor can access its http page on a 192.168 address.

From the router side of things the router assigns a DHCP lease then nothing.

Turning encryption off solves all this but leaves the system open.

The problem appears not to be on the router's side as the laptop I'm writing on can connect via WEP and WPA.

The laptop has connected to a WPA2 network before, so the card can handle it.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would double check that the key and the security settings match.

I have this (or similar) problems frequently when there are small problems such as wrong encryption selected.

Some wireless access points (possibly like this) may not even tell you when you have a wrong key - they just don't work.

Comment: nope same key, checked they are working on the same encryption the router defaults to WPA2-personal but I have tried every type it offers WPA,WPA2 & WEP each time checking the setting none of of them work.

Comment: @Gwilym - Does the router offer any sort of other security features such as isolation / mac filtering? It is also possible that it is simply dropping packets sent from your machine. (At a last resort, you may want to try a computer driver update and router firmware update if available to you).

Comment: yes it does have mac address filtering but I have made sure its disabled. How do I find out if its dropping the packets? I considered a driver update but it dont want to mess with it if I don't have to, and the laptop could connect to its old router with the same security AOK

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [Setting up your Huawei EchoLife HG520b](http://www.talktalk.co.uk/help/broadband/setting-up-your-huawei-echolife-hg520b-s.html). Also, the router admin/configure site might be disable for users over wireless access. If it is, it will only effect you if you are trying to configure or edit setting via the admin site when connected wireless. You should be able to access the internet with no problem.